# How to add scrollbars to your custom control in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, scrollbars

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357440/) I realized that perhaps I should have asked a more generic question. So, here goes:

In WPF, I'm creating a custom Panel-derived control. To that control I would like to add horizontal and vertical scrollbars and control them myself (get & set min/max/value/pagesize). How can I do this?

This is my first encounter with WPF, and I'm not yet familiar with Templates and Styles, so I don't know if answer lies there or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found it! Three easy steps:

1. Implement `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IScrollInfo` on your custom control;
2. Add your custom control to a `ScrollViewer`;
3. Set the `CanContentScroll` property on the `ScrollViewer` to `True`.

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The answer lies not in the Panel but in the [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx). Your panel shouldn't take care about scrollbars. Let ScrollViewer measure and arrange your panel. So your visual tree will include ScrollViewer first, then your panel:

```
    <ScrollViewer> 
      <cc:YourPanel/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

If you want to control ScrollViewer, you will probably want to either inherit from it or customize its template.

Comment: The problem is - my control may **NOT** change its size. ScrollViewer is based on checking the size of the child control.

Answer (score 0):

The Scroll Viewer needs to be in the template, around the border in the default setup:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type control:MyCustomControl}">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">                        
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Border>                        
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```